# vuejsで複数のコンポーネントを作りたい

Tags: javascript, vue.js

追記: 自己解決しました

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My Vue.js Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myCounter">
    <div>{{ count }}</div>
    <button v-on:click="count ++">Up</button>
  </div>
  <script src="./js/vue.js"></script>
  <script>
    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#myCounter',
      data: {
        count: 0
      },
      methods: {
        countUp: function(){
          this.count++;
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

サンプルをみてカウンターを作りました。
ページ内に複数のカウンターを設置して、それぞれの値が連動するようにするにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

Comment: 「それぞれの値が連動する」とは具体的にどのようなことですか？例えばカウンタ１が１０になるとカウンタ２が１つ繰り上がるとか？

Comment: カウンタ1とカウンタ2が持っているcountという値が常に同じということです。カウンタ1がカウントアップすれば、カウンタ2もカウントアップするというように。

Comment: `<div id="myCounter">` 配下であれば`<div>{{ count }}</div>`をもう一つ置くことで同じ値を表示できます。

Comment: 例えば「いいね 」ボタンのように記事の上と下に表示させたいという場合など、遠くにまたがっている場合はどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

Comment: 同じ配下にあれば離れていても大丈夫です。

Comment: 自己解決された場合は、自身で回答を投稿されてアクセプト（承認）できるようになったらアクセプトして質問を締め切ってください。

Answer (score 1):

他にも方法はあると思いますが、
**同じ値を表示する**だけなら、
単に同じ`<div id="myCounter">`配下に複数配置するだけでよいです。
これが単純で簡単な実現方法だと思います。
「遠くにまたがって」いても大丈夫です。

```
<div id="myCounter">
    <div>{{ count }}</div>
    <button v-on:click="count ++">Up</button>
    <div>
    別の内容<br />
    あれや<br />
    これや<br />
    間に色々ある<br />
    </div>
    <div>{{ count }}</div>
    <button v-on:click="count ++">Up</button>
</div>
```

Comment: 単一ファイルコンポーネント化した場合に「別の内容」の部分が辛くなりそうに感じています。
既存のブログの記事などはサーバーサイドでレンダリングされているので、たとえば底に組み込みたくなった場合は記事もajaxで取得しなければならず辛くなりそうに感じています。
SPAよりにならずに、どうにか小さく始めたいのですが。

Comment: 問題になる状況がいまいちよくイメージできないので、質問を編集して問題となるような状況を**具体的に**、追加して説明して頂けますか？